# Ctrl + → to have the same effect as ⌥ + →

Tags: keyboard, windows, switching

How can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> to have the same effect as <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>, i.e. move to the previous/next word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) has this functionality:

[image]